# Flutter: firebase_performance plugin fails pod install for iOS

Tags: firebase, flutter, rubygems, cocoapods, firebase-performance

When I add firebase_performance (0.3.2) to my pubspec.yaml the pod install fails. I have shown the output below.

Flutter doctor has 0 issues.

I am not really sure which error the firebase_performance plugin is making.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in my_app...                          1.6s
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             11.7s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
     
    ...

    [!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has libraries with conflicting names: libgoogleutilities.a.

    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:67:in `verify_no_duplicate_names'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in `each_key'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:48:in `block in verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:47:in `verify_no_duplicate_framework_and_library_names'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:37:in `validate!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:590:in `validate_targets'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:158:in `install!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:342: warning: URI.escape is obsolete

    ...

    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:342: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:114: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader/request.rb:61: warning: The called method `slug' is defined here
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:100: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/downloader/request.rb:61: warning: The called method `slug' is defined here

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this by deleting the Podfile.lock file then restarting the application.